# Cant register HUB again after changing Site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, hub-site, storage

Goal was to rename URL for SharePoint Online HUB Site. I tested on DEV tenant to unregister HUB Site, Change the URL and Register again. it was working, all sites get connected again back to the Site with new URL.

After I unregistered the HUB, switched the URL on live tenant I cannot "re-register" a HUB from that site with this error:

`The website has exceeded the maximum storage limit for files. To free up space, delete files you don't need and empty the Recycle Bin.` (translated with Google Translate)

- Recycle bin is empty
- I tried to expand the storage for that site with extra 100GB (Site size: ~10MB)
- Tenant storage have more than enough space
- tried to register with `Register-SPOHubSite` or `Register-PnPHubSite` with same error from SP server

Any ideas? I am wondering that maybe crawl needs to happen?

Comment: It is recommended to check the following uls log to see if you can find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: It was SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question: all it took was to wait.